# Get the output from Tcl C Procedures

Tags: tcl

I have a C shell that usually calls Tcl routines using [`Tcl_Eval`](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/CEval.html). Normally I was fine with just executing what the user typed and getting some status as a result. However, now I need to receive the actual stdio output from the command that user typed. Is there any way to get it using the [Tcl C procedures](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/index.html)?

As a side note: I need to figure out the list of current procedures available in the Tcl interpreter, both built in and user sourced. Basically, the output from `info procs *`.

Comment: Intercepting stdout from a process is quite intrusive. The Tcl-ish way to do it is to simply _not_ intercept it (and just grab the result instead), or if you have to intercept, to run the code in a subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could go like this:

1. Create a pipe by calling [`pipe(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).
2. Then in your interp:

   1. Close `stdout` by calling [`Tcl_Close()`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/OpenFileChnl.htm#M14) on it.
   2. Turn the write-end file descriptor of your pipe into Tcl's `stdout` channel by calling [`Tcl_MakeChannel()`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/OpenFileChnl.htm#M8) right after closing `stdout`.

   Or use just replace the `stdout` with a call to [`Tcl_SetStdChannel()`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/GetStdChan.htm).
3. Process the data coming from the pipe.

As to your side note — I think you could just call `Tcl_Eval()` in your interpreter and process the returned list using the list-processing functions from the Tcl API.

*Update* (from one of my comments): after some more thought I think it might be possible to just create a custom Tcl channel which implementation would just save away the data written to it and then register an instance of such a channel as stdout. See `Tcl_CreateChannel()` and `Tcl_RegisterChannel()`.

Comment: Processing lists sounds a lot simpler. But how will it really work? `Tcl_Eval` just returns status. Which command should I use to get the returned list?

Comment: @ilya1725, `Tcl_GetObjResult()`.

Comment: @ilya1725, after some more thought I think it might be possible to just create a custom Tcl channel which implementation would just save away the data written to it and then register an instance of such a channel as `stdout`. See `Tcl_CreateChannel()` and `Tcl_RegisterChannel()`.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the result from being echoed to the stdout?

Comment: @ilya1725, I don't understand this question: if you subverted the `stdout` channel, the output of the procs in your interp cannot be echoed to `stdout` kind of by definition. So what do you really mean? What did you do to capture output to `stdout` of your procs? Or may be they're writing to `stderr` instead?

Comment: Is there a limitation on how large a string can `Tcl_GetStringResult` return? Sorry, guys, but the documentation is not very exact.

Comment: @ilya1725, wherever a Tcl API call returns a C string, it's guaranteed to be terminated using the NUL-terminator standard for C (a byte with code 0x00), so the practical limit on the length of this string is dictated by the OS and current runtime conditions.

Comment: @ilya1725, note that if you're about to deal with the output of `info procs *` call, you're trying to do it wrong: you have the full power of the Tcl API at your disposal, so use the `Tcl_GetObjResult()` (which would return a Tcl list) and then use the [`Tcl_ListObj*()`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/ListObj.htm) API calls on this result. Retrieve a string representation only of individual objects representing the elements in the returned list.

Comment: Oh, nice. Yes, using lists is much better. Thanks, @kostix.

Comment: @ilya1725, you should probably take this as a rule of thumb: the "everything is a string" dogma was only true up to a certain (very old) release of Tcl. Since long ago, it's "everything is representable as a string", and all Tcl values have "native" internal representations, so if possible, always use those parts of Tcl API dealing with `Tcl_Obj`s -- this is both more convenient and faster.

Comment: @kostix A question about side note: How one can get returned list from Tcl_Eval? The return type of it is int which indicates to error.

Comment: @Ashot, as I've said in my second comment to this answer, one should use [`Tcl_GetObjResult()`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/SetResult.htm).

Comment: @kostix Do you mean that after calling `Tcl_eval(interp, "puts hello")` and  `Tcl_Obj* obj = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp)` I will get an object containing "hello"?

Comment: @Ashot, to make it more clear: at the C-level, each Tcl command sets the result of its work (either the actual result or an error message) using the special singleton "result object" maintained by each Tcl interpreter, and then returns one of the standard (like `TCL_OK`, `TCL_ERROR`, `TCL_BREAK` etc) or custom return codes signalizing the next command in the sequence how to interpret the object it left in the interp result.

Comment: @kostix So you are saying that if we close stdout of interpreter, and then evaluate something which needs to output, that will be an error, Interpreter will put the error in its result, and we can get the output from interp->result?

Comment: @Ashot, I'm not saying that! Please note very well that *the result* of a Tcl command, its *return code* and what it prints to *any* channel are unrelated things. Say, the `puts stdout foo` command, if succeeds, 1) resets the interp result; 2) returns `TCL_OK`, and sends the string `foo` to whatever is currently registered as the `stdout` channel. If you employ any of the techniques to subverting `stdout`, *you* are in charge of dealing with what is sent to your code by commands writing to `stdout`. This has nothing to do with what `Tcl_Eval()` returns or how it sets the interp result.

Comment: @Ashot, say, you create a custom channel, register it as `stdout` and then run `Tcl_Eval()` -- your channel driver will receive everything the commands of the evaluated script send to `stdout` *unless* some of the commands reopens (or closes) `stdout`.

Comment: @kostix So how you are getting the output of `puts stdout foo` using interpreter's result? You stated that you can do it in side note part of you answer.

Comment: @Ashot, I did not state that. Ilya was dealing with a call to `info procs *` which *does not* write anything to any channel and rather puts a list of strings to the interp result; so I showed him what's the best way to get hold on it. Please understand, that writing things to a channel (an `stdout` (which may be connected to a an interactive console or may be not), a file, a network socket) is a pure side effect, and it has nothing to do with the *result* of running a Tcl command. I tried to demonstrate this using that `puts` example -- please re-read it until this idea really sinks in.

Comment: @kostix I got it, thanks for such detailed explanations. Can you please answer this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063303/redirect-tcl-stdout-to-file-using-tcl-c-api.