# How to make Tcl interpreter source a file and open a pipe from shell command simultaneously?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there a way to make Tcl interpreter **source a file** and **open a pipe from shell command** parallel?

In more details, I have a GUI built from tcl/tk. I want my tcl script to source a setting file for GUI variables, and at the same time, open a pipe from **[tclsh setting_file]** to redirect the output to my GUI stdout.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that running the processing of the settings command in a subprocess is a good idea. Maybe a [safe interpreter](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/safe.htm) would be better?

Re trapping the output, you could [pick a technique for doing stdout capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530354/stdout-redirection) and then show the contents of the captured buffer in the GUI (after using [`encoding convertfrom`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/encoding.htm#M6) to get the characters back if you're using my solution to that problem) but you've got a general issue that it is possible for user code to block things up if it takes a long time to run. You *could* work around that by using threads, but I suspect it is easier to avoid the complexity and to just let badly-written setup code cause problems that the user will have to fix. (The `catch` command can help you recover from any outright errors during the sourcing of the settings file.)