# How to give output of puts to a proc as input?

Tags: tcl

I have a proc that print a list as formatted table. which is having use case like *print_table $temp*

How can i give output of a different proc where i print output with "puts" command as input to this proc *print_table* ?

```
set list1 {{abc 1} {defg 2} {hijlk 3} {lmn 4}}
proc abc { list1 } {
foreach lst $list1 {
   puts "$lst"
}
}

> abc $list1 
abc 1
defg 2
hijlk 3
lmn 4

> print_table $list1
 ==============
 | abc    | 1 |
 | defg   | 2 |
 | hijlk  | 3 |
 | lmn    | 4 |
 ==============
```

I want to have the below working

```
> print_table [abc $list1]
 ==============
 | abc    | 1 |
 | defg   | 2 |
 | hijlk  | 3 |
 | lmn    | 4 |
 ==============
```

Answer (score 1):

As Donal points out, it is preferable to make the printing code use a channel as an argument. Alternatively, if you don't have control over all printing procs, or you don't want to touch them, then use a channel interceptor (covered before, for [capturing Tcl test suite output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728794/redirect-test-results-for-tcltest/49730358#49730358)):

A channel interceptor is implemented as a channel transform; and has been covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530354/stdout-redirection/14538125#14538125) before.

### Step 1: Define a Channel Interceptor

```
oo::class create ChannelSink {
    variable buffer
    method initialize {handle mode} {
        if {$mode ne "write"} {error "can't handle reading"}
        return {finalize initialize write}
    }
    method finalize {handle} {
        # NOOP
    }

    method write {handle bytes} {
        append buffer $bytes
        return $bytes
    }

    method getCapture {} {
         set r $buffer
         unset buffer
         return $r
    }
}
```

The above snippet was derived/ stolen bluntly from [Donal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530354/stdout-redirection/14538125#14538125).

### Step 2: Register the interceptor with `stdout` around your printing code

```
set cs [ChannelSink new]
chan push stdout $cs

abc $list1

chan pop stdout
print_table [$cs getCapture]
```

You could pack the intercepting boilerplate into `print_table`, to make it look like: `print_table {abc $list1}`.

```
proc print_table {script} {
    # set up interception
    uplevel 1 $script
    # remove interception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways is to temporarily replace `puts`.

```
# Partial emulation of [puts] API; assumes we don't write to other files
proc capturing_puts {args} {
    global capturedStdout
    set value [lindex $args end]
    set args [lrange $args 0 end-1]
    if {"-nonewline" ni $args} {
        append value "\n"
    }
    append capturedStdout $value
}

# A helper procedure to install and restore the replacement [puts] implementation
proc capture {script} {
    global capturedStdout
    rename puts original_puts
    rename capturing_puts puts
    set capturedStdout ""

    try {
        uplevel 1 $script
    } finally {
        # Restore the original, even on error!
        rename puts capturing_puts
        rename original_puts puts
    }
    return $capturedStdout
}

# Now we can use it like this
set output [capture {
    abc $list1
}]
print_table $output
```

It's easier if you can make printing code take an (optional) argument that specifies the channel to write to. Then you don't need to mess around with output capturing at all.

---

I think it's possible to use a channel transform to do the capturing, which would be quite a bit less fragile than replacing a command with a slightly tricky API (`puts`) but writing them is rather more complex.

Comment: Thanks @DonalFellows. Not sure if i understood the solution fully, but this solutions doesnt seem to produce the intended output. I  just see output as `abc 1
defg 2
hijlk 3
lmn 4`  I have many such procs (like abc example), so changing the puts to channeled output would be tedious, so would like to use what ever outputs they produce into formatted table.

Comment: You're going to have to make code changes whatever solution you come up with. Utilize your editor's global search'n'replace to minimize the tedium.

Comment: @TradeCoder The example I wrote was confusing because I misread your question slightly. Updated…

Comment: close to what was needed, need some final refinement.. new to posting comments, so couldnt post the code in comment, but added as new answer for details

Answer (score 0):

@Donal, @mrcalivin, both your solutions were close to what i was expecting. But it printed all data in a single col.

suggested code gave output like below:

```
> print_table  [capture {abc $list1}]                    
 ========
 | abc   
 | 1     
 | defg  
 | 2     
 | hijlk 
 | 3     
 | lmn   
 | 4     
 ========
```

I have put the code of print_table, may be i can add the details of the proc print_table, if it makes more sense to make any changes, which i am currently inputting a list name **table**. There could have been much better way to code this proc.

```
proc print_table { table } {
    set col_len [llength [lindex $table 0]]
    for {set i 0} {$i < $col_len} { incr i } { set col_wid($i) 0 }
    foreach line $table {
        for {set i 0} {$i < $col_len} { incr i } { 
            set temp_col_width($i) [string length [lindex $line $i]];
            if { $col_wid($i) > $temp_col_width($i) } { set col_wid($i) $col_wid($i) } else { set col_wid($i) $temp_col_width($i) }
        }
    }
    set total_col 0; for {set i 0} {$i < $col_len} { incr i } { set total_col [expr $total_col +  $col_wid($i) ] } ; set total_col [expr $total_col + (($col_len-2) * 2) + 9 ];
    set table_length [llength $table]; set j 0 ; 
    foreach line $table {
      set line1 ""; set line2 "";
      for {set i 0} {$i < $col_len} { incr i } {
        if { $i == 0 } {
          append line1 " | [format "%-$col_wid($i)s" [lindex $line $i]] " 
        } elseif { $i == [expr $col_len -1] } {
          append line1 " | [format "%-$col_wid($i)s" [lindex $line $i]] |" 
        } else  {
          append line1 "| [format "%-$col_wid($i)s" [lindex $line $i]] "
        }
      }

      if { $j == 0 } {
        puts " [string repeat = [expr [string length $line1]-1]]"; 
        puts "$line1";
        #puts " [string repeat = [expr [string length $line1]-1]]"; 
      } elseif { $j == 1 && $j == [expr $table_length - 1] } {
        puts "$line1" ;puts " [string repeat = [expr [string length $line1]-1]]"
      } elseif { $j == [expr $table_length - 1] } {
        puts "$line1" ; puts " [string repeat = [expr [string length $line1]-1]]";
      } else { puts "$line1" }
       incr j;
    }
}
```