# How to use > to redirect output in tclsh

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I'm trying to see if I can redirect the output of tclsh to a specific file via >

for example

```
puts "123" > test.log

set a 123 > test.log

procTest {a b} > test.log
```

No good ideas at the moment.

Comment: What do you want exactly? `puts` has output but an empty result, and `set` has no output and (usually) a non-empty result.

Comment: Are you bothered by the output in an **interactive** tclsh session?

Comment: @glenn I would like to complete this function, which is very common in linux, and I am indeed not particularly familiar with tcl.

Comment: @Donal I may not have expressed it correctly, I want to redirect the output to the specified file via the > symbol, usually for commands that have output.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to guess, just read the documentation:

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Tutorial+Lesson+24

and

https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm

Answer (score 0):

Redirection with `> filename` is only supported by `exec` (and `open |...`; that uses the same engine as `exec`). It's not a general feature of the wider language, and isn't ever going to be (`>` and `<` are used for other purposes by well known packages.)

For commands that *print* output, you can redirect with a variation on my answer to this question:

- [stdout redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530354/stdout-redirection/14538125)

```
oo::class create Redirect {
    variable f
    constructor {filename} {
        # Note that this is a binary file; conversion to bytes done by stdout channel
        set f [open $filename wb]
    }
    method initialize {handle mode} {
        if {$mode ne "write"} {error "can't handle reading"}
        return {finalize initialize write}
    }
    method finalize {handle} {
        close $f
    }

    method write {handle bytes} {
        puts -nonewline $f $bytes
        # Return the empty string, as we are swallowing the bytes
        return ""
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
# Attach the redirect
chan push stdout [Redirect new outputfile.txt]

# Call code to do the writes here
puts "this is a test; hello world!"

# Stop redirecting
chan pop stdout
```

This won't work for use of `@stdout` in `exec` (or `open |...`). Making those work will require the use of `dup` from the TclX package.

```
package require Tclx

# Do the redirection
set saved [dup stdout]
set f [open outputfile.txt]
dup $f stdout

# Generate the output
puts "this is a test; hello world!"

# Restore
dup $saved stdout
close $saved
close $f
```

---

When doing things like this, it's probably best to use a helper procedure:

```
proc redirectStdout {filename body} {
    set saved [dup stdout]
    set f [open $filename]
    dup $f stdout
    try {
        uplevel 1 $body
    } finally {
        dup $saved stdout
        close $saved
        close $f
    }
}
# proc redirectStdout {filename body} {
#     chan push stdout [Redirect new $filename]
#     try {
#         uplevel 1 $body
#     } finally {
#         chan pop stdout
#     }
# }

redirectStdout outputfile.txt {
    puts "this is a test; hello world!"
}
```