# TEE for Tcl 8.5

Tags: tcl

I have a tee program from Schelte Bron that works great in TCL 8.6, however, I am trying to adapt our scripts to work with an EDA tool (Xilinx 2023.02) that uses TCL 8.5.   I get errors when I try the code in 8.5.   Any recommendations as to what the syntax is for 8.5:

```
namespace eval tee {
    variable methods {initialize finalize write}
    namespace ensemble create -subcommands {replace append channel} \
      -unknown [namespace current]::default
    namespace ensemble create -command transchan -parameters fd \
      -subcommands $methods
}

proc tee::default {command subcommand args} {
    return [list $command replace $subcommand]
}

proc tee::channel {chan fd} {
    chan push $chan [list [namespace which transchan] $fd]
    return $fd
}

proc tee::replace {chan file} {
    return [channel $chan [open $file w]]
}

proc tee::append {chan file} {
    return [channel $chan [open $file a]]
}

proc tee::initialize {fd handle mode} {
    variable methods
    return $methods
}

proc tee::finalize {fd handle} {
    close $fd
}

proc tee::write {fd handle buffer} {
#    puts -nonewline $fd $buffer
    # Remove Null and change crcrlf to crlf
    puts -nonewline $fd [regsub -all \r\n [regsub -all \x00 $buffer ""] \n]
#    return [regsub -all {<[^>]*>} $buffer ""]  ;# this works for ModelSim batch but not GHDL
    return $buffer
}
```

I start the scripts by calling StartTranscript:

```
proc StartTranscript {FileName} { 

    set LogFile  [open ${FileName} w]
    tee channel stderr $LogFile
    tee channel stdout $LogFile
}
```

And end it by calling StopTranscript:

```
proc DefaultVendor_StopTranscript {{FileBaseName ""}} {
    flush stdout
    chan pop stdout
    chan pop stderr
  }
}
```

If there is a simpler way to do this, I am open to that too.  All I need to do is capture everything that goes to either stdout or stderr into a log file.

Unfortunately the current solution uses code that is needs TCL 8.6 and I am not sure what I can and cannot delete.

Comment: You should have included the error message...

Comment: I noticed that this is a recurring topic of the OP. Did you consider some old-style (< 8.6) approach, like [replacing `puts`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530354/stdout-redirection/14536132#14536132) ? You do not detail our requirements/ constraints.

Comment: @mrcalvin   I am in a TCL environment.   I am trying to catch output of EDA simulators.  The output is on stdout and stderr.   The information on stdout or stderr can come from C or other language (one uses Ada) - so replacing puts is not an option.   It has to run in either windows or linux.   The 8.6 solution has more complexity than I understand - there are man pages on Channel, but I have yet to find a decent tutorial that explains the concepts of what is being done there.   Maybe there is a much simpler solution that the current 8.6 solution.

Comment: @JimLewis Ad: "catch output of EDA simulators." How are you integrating with the EDA simulators from within Tcl: `open`, `exec` ?

Comment: For some we run in their TCL based GUI.   For others, we start TCLSH and run their simulator from the tclsh command line - this case is never a problem as the TCL version is a matter of a properly updated OS.

Comment: I see, so it is Tcl 8.5 in the Tcl-based GUI. What about calling out to a system-wide Tcl (8.6) from the Tcl-8.5-based GUI, so that the two cases become just one? Then you could benefit from Tcl 8.6 in both.

Comment: As a developer of an open source tool, I do not have control of whether a user's machine has TCL installed and available on it - particularly from a windows environment.   Hence, I am trying to work with what I do have - A TCL 8.5 environment in which I can temporarily redirect the output to a file.   I did put a request to the vendor (Xilinx) to upgrade to TCL 8.6 in the next revision.   It is hard to say what will happen.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a `chan push` in 8.5; that was added in 8.6. The underlying stackable transformation system *is* there (it was there to enable things like the extension for TLS sockets) but it isn't exported to scripts.

Either you write a bit of C code to implement the transformation and connect it up (not a part of the API that I know well), or in your case things are simple enough that you can put the transformation in a separate process, which can be a trivial Tcl script that works on binary data in and binary data out.

Or you use `chan create` (which was added in 8.5 if I read the docs right) and make the implementation redirect writes.

Comment: TCL has a large community of EDA tool users who are not TCL experts but instead are creating a tool flow work for us.   What we need is a set of abstractions - either in packages or part of the language - that make things like redirecting all of the tool output to both a file and the tool output.   So unfortunately while I can use the abstractions provided by Schelte Bron's program, I don't know how to update it - even with your suggestions to look at chan create.    Is there any tutorial on what chan is and how to use it?

Comment: The Tclers Wiki contains useful examples: See the `refchan` example at https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changing+stdout%2C+redefining+puts+and+avoiding+console+show. While this works for Tcl 8.5, I fear that this does not meet your requirements, mainly because yo want to maintain stdout so that your EDA tool captures on stdout/ stderr as before.

Comment: Thanks for the link.   That uses chan push, which I understand was not available in 8.5 - see Donal's answer above.

Comment: @JimLewis I am referring to the second example on that page.

Comment: @mrcalvin What happens to stdout after that completes.   Our process is that we catch all output during a build operation and then we restore stdout to what it was.